# RadioButtonのカスタムコントロールにenumのリストをバインドしたい

Tags: wpf, xaml

WPFで、同じ`GroupName`を持つ`RadioButton`のリストを構成するカスタムコントロールを作ろうとしています。
このカスタムコントロールは、次の`DependencyProperty`を持ちます。

`ItemsSource`：`enum`のコレクション（`enum`なら何でもOK）
`SelectedValue`：選択されている`RadioButton`に対応する`enum`の値

`enum`の値から`RadioButton`の表示テキスト(`Content`)への変換は、`IValueConverter`を実装して適当に処理しています。
`ItemsSource`から`RadioButton`を生成する処理には、`ItemsControl`を利用しました。

ここまでは問題なかったのですが、`SelectedValue`プロパティと、対応する`RadioButton`の`IsChecked`を結びつける方法が分かりません。
`ItemsControl`を使わず、XAMLで静的に作られたものであれば、各`RadioButton`の`CoverterParameter`に対応する`enum`の値を記述し、`Converter`に渡すだけで良いことは分かるのですが、動的にラジオボタンを作ろうとして詰まってしまいました。
下記のコードの、`ConvertParameter={Binding}`の部分が問題です。

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{
                             Binding SeletedValue,
                             Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonCheckedConverter},
                             ConverterParameter={Binding},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}
                         }"
                         GroupName="{Binding GroupName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                         Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonTextConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

このままでは

```
型 'Binding' の 'ConverterParameter' プロパティで 'Binding' を設定することはできません。
'Binding' は、DependencyObject の DependencyProperty でのみ設定できます。
```

というエラーが出てしまい、動作しません。
何とかして、`RadioButtonCheckedConverter`に各`RadioButton`にバインドされている`enum`の値を`ConverterParameter`として渡したいのですが・・・
どなたか何かご存知でしたら、教えてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

添付プロパティを使用して`RadioButton`の`Checked`イベントを拾ってやる必要があると思います。

```
public class Radio
{
    public static object GetSelectedValue(RadioButton obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(SelectedValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedValue(RadioButton obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(Radio), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedValueChanged) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

    private static void OnSelectedValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rb = (RadioButton)d;

        rb.Checked -= rb_Checked;
        rb.Checked += rb_Checked;
        rb_Checked(rb, null);
    }

    static void rb_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        if (rb.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SetSelectedValue(rb, rb.DataContext);
        }
    }
}
```

使用例

```
<RadioButton local:Radio.SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
```

Comment: 試してみましたが、OnSelectedValueChangedの引数dに、RadioButtonではなくRadioがきてしまい、うまくいきませんでした。

Comment: @mok2pok うーん、上のコードだとRadioはDependencyObjectではないのでdには入らないはずです。C#側は動作確認しましたので、何か誤解があるのでは無いかと思います。

Comment: 失礼しました。Radioクラスの使い方が間違っていたようです。おかげさまでうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

ListBoxに変更して、RadioButtonのIsCheckedとListBoxItemのIsSelectedをバインドすればよいのではないでしょうか。
以下はListBoxの背景色を消すためにいくつかスタイルを操作していますが、必要なのはRadioButtoのプロパティに行っているバインドのみです。

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"       
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Enumの要素一覧に変換するコンバーター -->
    <local:RadioTool x:Key="enumConverter"/>        
    <DataTemplate x:Key="radioTemplate">
        <!-- ListBoxの選択色を消すためにRadioButtonの外にGrid配置してます-->
        <Grid Background="{Binding Path=Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}">
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                         GroupName="{Binding Path=(local:RadioTool.GroupName),RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                         Content="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="listBoxItemStyle">
        <!-- ListBoxの選択色を消すためにボーダーなどを消す -->
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="listBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource radioTemplate}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource listBoxItemStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Style="{StaticResource listBoxStyle}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Type Visibility},Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}}"                                  
             local:RadioTool.GroupName="A" /><!-- 添付プロパティでRadioButtonのGroupNameを指定-->
    <ListBox Style="{StaticResource listBoxStyle}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Type  HorizontalAlignment},Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}}"                 
             local:RadioTool.GroupName="A"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
class RadioTool : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues((Type)value);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public static string GetGroupName(DependencyObject obj) { return (string)obj.GetValue(GroupNameProperty); }

    public static void SetGroupName(DependencyObject obj, string value) { obj.SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GroupName", typeof(string), typeof(RadioTool), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(string)));
}
```

以上は、Enumが重複しない単一の値のみで定義されている場合のみ有効です。

Answer (score 1):

`ConverterParameter`の値にはBindingできないので、他のアプローチを試すべきです。

やりたい事の本質としては「2つのBinding先の値と1つのUI要素を結び付けたい」という事でしょうから、`MultiBinding`と`IMultiValueConverter`を使えば実現できそうです。

```xml
<RadioButton Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonTextConverter}}" GroupName="{Binding GroupName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <RadioButton.IsChecked>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RadioButtonCheckedConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
            <Binding Path="" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </RadioButton.IsChecked>
</RadioButton>
```

上記コードはあくまで一例(動作検証していない)ですが、こういった形で実現が可能かと思います。

Comment: `IMultiValueConverter`の場合、`RadioButton`が区別できず`ConvertBack`の実装が困難です。